# How expensive is raise in Python?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

During development using drf, an efficient method for error handling was needed.

I found two methods, one using ErrorResponse created by inheriting Response, and one using APIException provided by drf.

The first method is done through return, and the second method uses the raise command.

I wonder which one is more efficient and why!

I apologize in advance for the question may be too vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if efficiency and CPU time is most important thing.

You have to understand Django [request-response cycle](https://medium.com/@ksarthak4ever/django-request-response-cycle-2626e9e8606e) first. The next step after `return Response` (or `raise Exception`) is not a client side browser but number of Middlewares that you imported in your application. And these Middlewares may be different depends on what happens inside View.

When you raising something you break this cycle flow.
Django handling raised exception, writing extra error logs, returning specified error response to client side. You don't have to care that all conditions of correct responses will be satisfied, because error already happens, it is already not correct. In other way returned Response will be delivered to client side by normal way. Django will care that all validations and steps will be passed before response reach a client.

If you need to save milliseconds by choosing between return / raise and deeply thinking about efficiency, at first stop using Django. Seriously. It is slowest framework even for python.

Comment: Hello, just interested what is the fastest framework in python for web dev?

Comment: I didn't measurements by myself and only trust my feelings and [public information](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+fastest+web+framework&oq=python+fastest+web+framework&aqs=edge..69i57j0i22i30j0i390l3j69i64.8222j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). I used Flask, FastAPI and Django in my work. Even if response time may be comparable for this trio, first two frameworks using much less resources than Django

Comment: @Flow you also should use python 3.10 and jump into 3.11 after release, because they're the fastest version available. The python dev team lately started to improve performance in various built-in methods and general code syntax so it's faster by some margin (I would say 20-40%).

Comment: @rzlvmp and Patryk Szczepański thanks for the information

Answer (score 1):

`raise` produces an error in the current level of the call stack. You can catch a raised error by covering the area where the error might be raised in a try and handling that error in an except.

`return` on the other hand, returns a value to where the function was called from, so returning an exception usually is not the functionality you are looking for in a situation like this, since the exception itself is not the thing triggering the except it is instead the raising of the exception that triggers it.

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#raise

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#return

So to answer your question I would `raise` because it is built for errors compared to `return`. Also, they are the same in speed/efficiency.